# SQL linking by Rank() Over

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to calculate days when the container is OUT of the facility, each time the container arrives it has different primary key but the same ID. Same container can leave and arrive multiple times but of course I have to count the days between the closest departure and arrival. I've been trying to do that using Rank() Over function by counting the departures and arrivals:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, datediff(day,c_out.time_out, c_in.time_In) as Days 
FROM

(SELECT Container_ID
, time_out
, RANK() OVER (PARTITION by Container_ID, order by time_out) as leave_no
FROM Containers
WHERE Departure_type='TRUCK'              --EDIT2 ************************************
) c_out INNER JOIN
(SELECT container_ID as Incoming_ID
, time_in
,RANK () OVER (PARTITION by Container_ID, order by time_in) as arrive_no
FROM Containers) c_in
ON c_out.container_id=c_in.incoming_id

WHERE c_out.leave_no=c_in.arrive_no+1
```

The idea here is to match the leaves to entries: if container left for the n-th time, the next arrival will be n+1

But as a result I receive something like

```
CONTAINER_ID   TIME_OUT    LEAVE_NO  INCOMING_ID  TIME_IN    ARRIVE_NO  DAYS
ABC123         2014-04-11     2      ABC123       2013-11-21   1         -141
```

EDIT: While the presented below solution DO work, I'd still like to know how to join on RANK()

EDIT2: Let me clarify: containers have to leave in particular way (one of possible ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something more brute-force, a bit like:

```
SELECT Container_ID
, time_out
, (select min(c2.time_in) 
      from Containers c2 
      where c2.container_ID = c1.container_ID 
      and c2.time_in > c1.time_out) as returned
FROM Containers c1
```

Comment: I'll tell you when the server will finish working on it... 10 minutes and still processing. Brute force is brute.

Comment: Is it finished yet?  ;-)

Comment: After proper indexing of the table it went pretty fast :)

Comment: Very glad to hear that.  Another feature of this technique is you get a lovely NULL if the item isn't returned.  You can expand on the technique by ensuring there isn't a second 'time_out' between the c1.time_out and c2.time_in, e.g. if it was recorded sent out twice.  It will be slower, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the rank calculations all at once:

```
with cte as (
   SELECT Container_ID
      , time_out
      , time_in
      , RANK() OVER (PARTITION by Container_ID order by time_out) as leave_no
      , RANK() OVER (PARTITION by Container_ID order by time_in) as arrive_no
   FROM Containers
)
select c_out.container_no
   , c_out.time_out
   , c_in.time_in, datediff(day,c_out.time_out, c_in.time_In)
from cte as c_out
join cte as c_in
   on c_out.container_id = c_in.container_id
   and c_out.leave_no = c_in.arrive_no + 1
```